# Model "CartItem" is not associated with model "Product" but it is?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

I’m writing a CakePHP plugin. In my plugin’s `AppModel` I have:

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Containable'
);
```

I then have two models: a `CartItem` and a `Product`. My `CartItem` model look like this:

```
<?php
class CartItem extends ShoppingCartAppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Cart',
        'Product'
    );
}
```

However, when calling the `Cart` model in my controller I get the following error:

> Warning (512): Model "CartItem" is not associated with model "Product" [CORE/Cake/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php, line 344]

Why is this, when I’ve defined that my `CartItem` model is associated to the `Product` model through a `belongsTo` association?

EDIT: I’ve narrowed my problem to where I attempt to fetch my cart and its contents in my `Cart` model. Here is the call:

```
public function findBySessionId($sessionId) {
    $cart = $this->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Cart.session_id' => $sessionId
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'CartItem' => array(
                'Product'
            )
        )
    ));
    return $cart;
}
```

Comment: Is it actually using your model file if you just use $this->find like that? Wouldn't you need $this->CartItem->find or else it will just use the generic appModel class?!

Comment: In my `CartController`, I want to be able to fetch a user’s cart, and the `CartItem`s and related `Product`s in that cart so I can display it to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Models in a plugin need the plugin name in the class name.

For example:

```
<?php
class Cart {

    public $hasMany = array(
        'CartItem' => array(
            'className' => 'ShoppingCart.CartItem'
        )
    );
}
```

Specifying the plugin name just in the association name caused an SQL error for me, so you can circumventing by specifying the class name—with plugin prefix—manually.

Comment: `Specifying the plugin name just in the association name` - if by that you mean the array key, it's the association alias - and putting a `.` in it will just cause general mayhem. The shorthand syntax (`$hasMany => array('Plugin.Model')`) is equivalent to the full syntax (`$hasMany => array('Model' => array('className' => 'Plugin.Model'))` - There's more about that [in the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-models). In any event though glad you found the solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes. Like I say, when I put the plugin name in the array key/association alias, it triggered the SQL error.

Answer (score 2):

### Model associations need a plugin prefix

From the question it is likely the Cart Model is defined like so:

```
    public $hasMany = array(
        'CartItem'
    );
}
```

This will mean that Cake is expecting the following:

```
app
    Model
        CartItem.php <- 'CartItem' means the model is in the App, not a plugin
    Plugin
        Model
            Cart.php
```

The App `CartItem` model doesn't exist, and therefore will be an instance of `AppModel`.

Always ensure that the plugin prefix is used (if appropriate) when defining model associations:

```
    public $hasMany = array(
        'ShoppingCart.CartItem' // Load the model from this same plugin
    );
}
```

Comment: I’m trying to load `CartItem`s (and related `Product`s) from my `Cart` model. I’ll update my question with the example call.

Comment: So how do I fix it so I can access the `Product` of each `CartItem` from `Cart`? I’ve not had this problem before working with the `Containable` behavior.

Comment: It’s `AppModel` but I’m sure my model’s named correctly: **CartItem.php**. Is it because it’s within a plugin and not the “main” app?

Comment: Well that's a different permutation of "model file is misnamed" I've updated the answer

Comment: I thought that, but when I add the `ShoppingCart.` prefix, I get an SQL error: `Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.\`CartItem\` WHERE \`ShoppingCart\`.\`CartItem\`.cart_id = (2)' at line 1`

Comment: I don't know what your comment is related to.